# sequential functions javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having major trouble getting my app to behave while loading. I don't think it is very fair to users to allow them access to the app until it's finished loading and is ready / responsive.

Please note: every thing else works fine in my app I just can't get functions to run in order.

```
function LOADINGapp(){
    //app loads but allows user to enter before loading is finished
    $.when(getToday()).then(reorderdivs()).then(getSomething()).then(setupSomethingElse()).then(loadAnotherSomething()).then(INITapp());

    //app stops dead at getToday but (Crome javascript console) no errors
    getToday(function(){reorderdivs(function(){getSomething(function(){setupSomethingElse(function(){loadAnotherSomething(function(){INITapp();});});});});});

    //app loads but allows user to enter before loading is finished
    getToday(reorderdivs(),getSomething(),setupSomethingElse(),loadAnotherSomething(),INITapp());

    //getToday();
    //reorderdivs();
    //getSomething();
    //setupSomethingElse();
    //loadAnotherSomething();
    //INITapp();
    }
function INITapp(){
    $('#SPLASH').hide();
    }
```

Can someone please assist me, I don't understand. Done and doing a tone of research to get this to behave.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by jumping (only allowing my LOADINGapp function to do one thing at a time) so it works in stages. once a stage (a function) is complete it jumps back into the LOADINGapp function.

```
var L=0;

function LOADINGapp(){
    if(L==0){getToday();}
    else if(L==1){reorderdivs();}
    else if(L==2){getSomething();}
    else if(L==3){setupSomethingElse();}
    else if(L==4){loadAnotherSomething();}
    else if(L==5){INITapp();};
    }
function INITapp(){
    $('#SPLASH').hide();
    }
```

example:

```
function getSomething(){
    //app suff
    //app suff
    //app suff
    L = 3;
    LOADINGapp();
    }
```

the only thing I will improve is just do L++; at the end of LOADINGapp as it saves writing it all over the place. PS:thanks for the efforts guys

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used when/then from jquery before, but it looks like you need to pass the pointers to the methods. Right now you are actually executing them all at once. Try:

```
$.when(getToday())
 .then(reorderdivs)
 .then(getSomething)
 .then(setupSomethingElse)
 .then(loadAnotherSomething)
 .then(INITapp);
```

(Notice the missing parentheses)

Also, be aware the only true asynchronous object in JS is an AJAX call. setTimeout is NOT asynchronous, it is a queueing method.  Read John Resig's post:

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: this produces no error but lets the user in before loading has finished.

Comment: I would suggest stepping through your code with firebug. put breakpoints in your functions and see when they are executed. Or try a simpler demo to understand the flow before implementing your business logic.

Comment: Also - is there a specific reason for using the when/then methods? After reading the docs they seem more for handling ajax calls then anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably something to do with asynchronous functions. So you could try making those functions with a callback, as mentioned here: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/JavaScript-Function-Tips-and-Tricks.aspx.

Comment: I don't any difference in using callback() or loadAnotherSomething() , am I wrong?

Comment: @BenMuircroft - What you need to do is add a callback parameter to loadAnotherSomething() etc